# Application Priority on Screen

Tags: android, android-studio, service

Is there any way to give an app permission to launch an activity on top of another app? For example, when someone calls you on your phone while you're using another app, the calling activity takes priority.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to grant permission, add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

to your manifest file.

to display view on top of other apps use the window manager

```
WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
WindowManager.LayoutParams paramsForButton = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT;
windowManager.addView(yourViewWindowManager.LayoutParams, paramsForButton);
```